# Powershell 2.0 Write output to display and append to file

Tags: powershell

I would like to display a message in PowerShell and append the message to a log file.   In PowerShell 4.0 you can use Tee-Object -Append but I don't think they have the -Append option in PowerShell 2.0.    Is there an simple way to write a message to the screen and log file at the same time?

Unfortunately I can't upgrade to PowerShell 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` [cmdlets](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=289793) (remember to change the dropdown to 3.0 so you can see the 2.0 features). You might need to collapse your output file descriptors using [redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) if you wish to capture verbose, warning, error, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works, although it's a bit long:

```
    | %{write-host $_; out-file -filepath "$LOG" -inputobject $_ -append}
```